# Display multiple Dynamic IPropertyPanePage.groups Sharepoint Online Framework

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-webparts, reactjs

Hi everyone I'm creating a Web Part in order to display a full width Bootstrap grid with you can personalize Sharepoint pages. Selecting the Grid Size options the Grid is created and everything works fine. But I need also to display the properties from a single cell in order to customize all the Grid Cells. I tried everything but i Can only display one object. If im right the IPropertyPanePage.groups is an array of Objects but I just can show one object at the time. I know that this could be easy for some of you but I really need a help. I'm using React framework to build the webpart.

```
    return {
      pages: [
        {
          header: {
            description: strings.PropertyPaneDescription
          },
          groups:[
            {
              groupName: strings.BasicGroupName,
              groupFields: [
                PropertyPaneDropdown('GridSize', {
                  label: 'Please Select the Size of the Grid',
                  disabled: false,
                  options: this.gridOptions
                })
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          //Page 2
          displayGroupsAsAccordion: true,
          header: {
            description: 'Cells Properties'
          },
          groups: [          
              this.getCellProps()  
          ]
        }
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

function code below

```
  private getCellProps() {

    var totalcells = 1 * 4;
    console.log('total=' + totalcells);

    if (totalcells != 0) {

      var listPanels =[];

      for (var x = 1; x <= totalcells; x++) {
      //console.log(x);

        var singlePanel = {
          groupName: "Panel"+x,
          isCollapsed: true,
          groupFields: [
            PropertyPaneHorizontalRule(),
            PropertyPaneTextField('Title', {
              label: 'Title Panel',
              placeholder: 'Insert Title',
            }),
            PropertyPaneTextField('ImgPath', {
              label: 'Image Path',
              placeholder: 'Insert Path Image URL',
            }),
            PropertyPaneTextField('Link', {
              label: 'Link Image',
              placeholder: 'Insert Link',
            }),
            PropertyPaneDropdown('WidthValue', {
              label: 'Width Value',
              disabled: false,
              options: this.widthOption
            }),
            PropertyFieldToggleWithCallout('toggleInfo', {
              calloutTrigger: CalloutTriggers.Click,
              key: 'toggleInfo',
              label: 'Disable Link Pane',
              calloutContent: React.createElement('p', {}, 'With this control you can enable or disable the link for this cell'),
              onText: 'Disabled',
              offText: 'Enabled',
              checked: this.properties.toggleInfo
            }),
            PropertyFieldToggleWithCallout('IsHidden', {
              calloutTrigger: CalloutTriggers.Click,
              key: 'IsHidden',
              label: 'Hidden/Show Panel',
              calloutContent: React.createElement('p', {}, 'With this control you can Hidden or Show the cell'),
              onText: 'Hidden',
              offText: 'Show',
              checked: this.properties.IsHidden
            }),
            PropertyFieldToggleWithCallout('IsCircle', {
              calloutTrigger: CalloutTriggers.Click,
              key: 'IsCircle',
              label: 'Square/Circle Image',
              calloutContent: React.createElement('p', {}, 'With this control you can Modify the shape of the image'),
              onText: 'Circle',
              offText: 'Square',
              checked: this.properties.IsCircle
            }),
            PropertyFieldToggleWithCallout('NoTitle', {
              calloutTrigger: CalloutTriggers.Click,
              key: 'NoTitle',
              label: 'Enable/Disable Title',
              calloutContent: React.createElement('p', {}, 'With this control you can enable or disable the Title '),
              onText: 'Disabled',
              offText: 'Enabled',
              checked: this.properties.NoTitle
            })
          ]
        };
        listPanels.push(singlePanel);
        console.log(listPanels.length);
      }
      return listPanels[3];
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like it'll be a cool sample.

You weren't far from getting something that works. If I can give you a little trick: take advantage of Typescript and define what each variable type will be. That way, it'll help identify issues quickly in your code.

For example, your `getCellProps` method returns (or should return) an array of `IPropertyPaneGroup`, so declare your function so that Typescript will scream at you if you don't return the right type of value, as follows:

```
private getCellProps(): IPropertyPaneGroup[] {
```

With that in mind, I have changed your code so that you return an array of `IPropertyPaneGroup` as follows:

```
  protected getPropertyPaneConfiguration(): IPropertyPaneConfiguration {
    return {
      pages: [
        {
          header: {
            description: strings.PropertyPaneDescription
          },
          groups:[
            {
              groupName: strings.BasicGroupName,
              groupFields: [
                PropertyPaneDropdown('GridSize', {
                  label: 'Please Select the Size of the Grid',
                  disabled: false,
                  options: [{key: 'Big', text: 'Big'},{key: 'Small', text: 'Small'}]
                })
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          //Page 2
          displayGroupsAsAccordion: true,
          header: {
            description: 'Cells Properties'
          },
          groups: this.getCellProps()
        }
      ]
    };
  }

  private getCellProps(): IPropertyPaneGroup[] {

    const totalcells: number = 1 * 4;
    console.log('total=' + totalcells);

    if (totalcells != 0) {

      const listPanels: IPropertyPaneGroup[] =[];

      for (var x = 1; x <= totalcells; x++) {

        var singlePanel: IPropertyPaneGroup = {
          groupName: "Panel"+x,
          isCollapsed: true,
          groupFields: [
            PropertyPaneHorizontalRule(),
            PropertyPaneTextField('Title', {
              label: 'Title Panel',
              placeholder: 'Insert Title',
            }),
            PropertyPaneTextField('ImgPath', {
              label: 'Image Path',
              placeholder: 'Insert Path Image URL',
            }),
            PropertyPaneTextField('Link', {
              label: 'Link Image',
              placeholder: 'Insert Link',
            }),
            PropertyPaneDropdown('WidthValue', {
              label: 'Width Value',
              disabled: false,
              options: [{key: 'One', text: 'One'}, {key: 'Two', text: 'Two'}, {key: 'Three', text: 'Three'}]
            }),
            PropertyFieldToggleWithCallout('toggleInfo', {
              calloutTrigger: CalloutTriggers.Click,
              key: 'toggleInfo',
              label: 'Disable Link Pane',
              calloutContent: React.createElement('p', {}, 'With this control you can enable or disable the link for this cell'),
              onText: 'Disabled',
              offText: 'Enabled',
              checked: this.properties.toggleInfo
            }),
            PropertyFieldToggleWithCallout('IsHidden', {
              calloutTrigger: CalloutTriggers.Click,
              key: 'IsHidden',
              label: 'Hidden/Show Panel',
              calloutContent: React.createElement('p', {}, 'With this control you can Hidden or Show the cell'),
              onText: 'Hidden',
              offText: 'Show',
              checked: this.properties.IsHidden
            }),
            PropertyFieldToggleWithCallout('IsCircle', {
              calloutTrigger: CalloutTriggers.Click,
              key: 'IsCircle',
              label: 'Square/Circle Image',
              calloutContent: React.createElement('p', {}, 'With this control you can Modify the shape of the image'),
              onText: 'Circle',
              offText: 'Square',
              checked: this.properties.IsCircle
            }),
            PropertyFieldToggleWithCallout('NoTitle', {
              calloutTrigger: CalloutTriggers.Click,
              key: 'NoTitle',
              label: 'Enable/Disable Title',
              calloutContent: React.createElement('p', {}, 'With this control you can enable or disable the Title '),
              onText: 'Disabled',
              offText: 'Enabled',
              checked: this.properties.NoTitle
            })
          ]
        };
        listPanels.push(singlePanel);
        console.log(listPanels.length);
      }
      return listPanels;
    }
  }
}
```

It gives you the results that you want (I think). Sorry if I hard-coded some dummy choices in my code sample, I didn't know what your options were.

I hope this helps?

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!
I even tried returning a IProperty PanelGroup but when I returned it without the new const that you inserted I had an error like "GroupName was missing".
Now Everything Works fine thanks to you.
I was really frustrated.
If someone need i was following this example:
[link](https://sharepointframework-dev.blogspot.com/2019/04/conditional-properties.html)